# NoMethodError: undefined method <<

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an another error `NoMethodError`:

> undefined method <<' for nil:NilClass from
>   app/operations/bank_accounts/validate_new_transaction.rb:31:‌​in
>   validate_existence_of_account!'

```
def validate_existence_of_account! 
  if @bank_account.blank?
    @errors << "Account not found" 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code? What does your controller look like?

Comment: So where did you define `@errors`?  It looks like `@errors` has never been defined and so contains nil.

Comment: def initialize(amount:, transaction_type:, bank_account_id:)
      
      @erros = []
    end

Answer (score 3):

Your variable `@errors` is `nil`, you need to set it to `Array` (I assume that is what you want) before calling `<<` on it like so:

```
@errors = []
@errors << "foobar"
```

**UPDATE**

You have a typo in your `initialize` method, use `@errors` instead of `@erros`.

Comment: how can i fix it ?

Comment: @Michael Could you post your `validate_new_transaction.rb` file?

Comment: do you see the file i posted ?

Comment: thanks you gars, i must to be verry concentrate !!! verry thanks you ! god bless you !

Comment: @Michael Glad to help! And remember to accept the answer (by clicking the tick).